# SQL Server Select specific rows within a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I'm using SQL Server 2012. Below is an example dataset

```
Prefix_Suffix   First_Nm    Last_Nm Acct_Registration_Line_1    Acct_Registration_Line_2    secondlevel TopLevel
NULL    Jane    Smith   NULL    NULL    smith1-rep  abc-quarterly
NULL    John    Smith   NULL    NULL    smith1-rep  abc-quarterly
Jane Smith  NULL    NULL    IRA FBO Jane Smith (EQUITY) PERSHING LLC AS CUSTODIAN   smith1-rep  abc-quarterly
Jane Smith  NULL    NULL    IRA FBO Jane Smith (FI) PERSHING LLC AS CUSTODIAN   smith1-rep  abc-quarterly
John Smith  NULL    NULL    IRA FBO John Smith (EQUITY) PERSHING LLC AS CUSTODIAN   smith1-rep  abc-quarterly
John Smith  NULL    NULL    IRA FBO John Smith (FI) PERSHING LLC AS CUSTODIAN   smith1-rep  abc-quarterly
```

This data appears in a variety of sequences, sometimes there are only rows where First_Nm (First Name) and Last_Nm (Last Name) are populated and Prefix_Suffix is NULL. Sometimes Prefix_Suffix is populated and the first and last name fields are NULL. I can handle if it is all one or all the other being NULL. The rows I'm struggling with are when both NULL scenarios appear within a group. A group is indicated by having the same value in the secondlevel column.

If within a group Prefix_Suffix contains a value and first and last name are null & also there are rows where First and last name contain a value and Prefix_Suffix is null THEN I do not want any rows that have a value for Prefix_Sufix. So when the example dataset occurs I would want to filter it to eliminate the 4 rows where Prefix_Suffix is populated. Again I only want this outcome in groupings that have alternating NULLS between Prefix_Suffix & First_nm, Last_Nm.

Desired Result

```
Prefix_Suffix   First_Nm    Last_Nm Acct_Registration_Line_1    Acct_Registration_Line_2    secondlevel TopLevel
NULL    Jane    Smith   NULL    NULL    smith1-rep  abc-quarterly
NULL    John    Smith   NULL    NULL    smith1-rep  abc-quarterly
```

Here is the current select statement. I was trying to isolate the 2 NULL scenarios with UNION ALL but that was not enough.

```
WITH DATA AS
(
SELECT *,
COUNT(Acct_Nbr) OVER (PARTITION BY acct_nbr)AcctCount
 FROM ##temptable 
 WHERE  1 = 1
 AND acct_holder_role_cd <> 'sec'
)
SELECT * 
INTO ##PrefixedAccounts
FROM DATA
WHERE AcctCount = 1 AND Last_Nm IS NULL;
SELECT 
RcdTypId,Acct_Nbr,Acct_Short_Nm,Acct_Holder_Typ_Cd,Acct_Holder_Role_Cd, Prefix_Suffix
,First_Nm,Middle_Nm,Last_Nm,Acct_Registration_Line_1,Acct_Registration_Line_2
INTO ##temptable2
 FROM ##temptable 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT ##PrefixedAccounts.Acct_Nbr
FROM ##PrefixedAccounts 
WHERE ##PrefixedAccounts.Acct_Nbr = ##temptable.Acct_Nbr
);
WITH DATA AS
(
SELECT  
RcdTypId,Acct_Nbr,Acct_Short_Nm,Acct_Holder_Typ_Cd,Acct_Holder_Role_Cd,Prefix_Suffix,
NULL AS First_Nm, Middle_Nm, Last_Nm,Acct_Registration_Line_1,Acct_Registration_Line_2
FROM ##PrefixedAccounts
UNION ALL
SELECT
RcdTypId,Acct_Nbr,Acct_Short_Nm,Acct_Holder_Typ_Cd,Acct_Holder_Role_Cd,NULL AS Prefix_Suffix,First_Nm,Middle_Nm,Last_Nm,
NULL AS Acct_Registration_Line_1,NULL AS Acct_Registration_Line_2
FROM ##temptable2
)
SELECT * INTO ##ClientNames FROM DATA
DROP TABLE ##temptable2
DROP TABLE ##PrefixedAccounts

-- SELECT * FROM ##ClientNames ORDER BY prefix_Suffix desc
-- DROP TABLE ##ClientNames

SELECT distinct
cl.Prefix_Suffix,cl.First_Nm,cl.Last_Nm,cl.Acct_Registration_Line_1,cl.Acct_Registration_Line_2
,at.secondlevel,at.TopLevel FROM ##ClientNames cl
INNER JOIN ##AddeparTemplate at ON cl.Acct_nbr = at.owned
WHERE 1 = 1
AND (cl.Last_Nm IS NOT NULL OR cl.Acct_Registration_Line_1 IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY cl.prefix_suffix, at.secondlevel
DROP TABLE ##ClientNames
```

Comment: Provide your current SELECT statement

Comment: added select statement

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by coalesce(prefix_suffix, first_nm + ' ' + last_nm)
                                order by (case when first_nm is not null then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from ##temptable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: It's not quite working. When there's any values in LastName in a group. I don't need any rows where Prefix_Suffix is NULL. I only want Prefix_Suffix is all lastName values are NULL in a group.